# Remove auto-generated index row numbers in R table

Tags: r

I am loading a table from sql into R, calling it dataframe.

dataframe <- sqlQuery(dbo, dataFinal)

My dataframe then returns the below - which includes this number index which I do not want.

```
    Column1   Column2    Score
1       a          e        5
2       b          f        5 
3       c          g        8
4       d          h        7
```

What do I need to convert **dataframe** to such that I return the below:

```
Column1   Column2    Score
   a          e        5
   b          f        5 
   c          g        8
   d          h        7
```

I want to be able to call this table, so a print() will not work.

Comment: Isn't there a `rownames` argument in the function so you can set it to `FALSE`? ( I am not familiar with that function)

Comment: Per the documentation (`?data.frame`) "A data frame is a list of variables of the same number of rows with unique row names, given class "data.frame". If no variables are included, the row names determine the number of rows."  You can hide the row names with various print functions (`print(df1, row.names = FALSE)`, which you said you don't want) but they're an integral part of the data.frame class.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but I think you can just ignore them. If you look at `cars` (or any other built in data.frame) you will see that it shows the rownames there also, but they won't interfere with you using them (if that is what you mean by *want to be able to call this table*). As already mentioned by Greg, only when we print the data, only then should we care *what* is shown (and use the corresponding print functions `row.names` argument)